# Which templating system to use for Javascript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a few years I've been using `jQuery.tmpl()` as the templating system in my projects. However lately I've been hearing that this project is deprecated / no longer being developed.

My question is, which is the best templating / views system that's officially endorsed by jquery as the replacement for jQuery.tmpl ?

Comment: or http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: Yeah mustache is nice. I don't think there's anything "official".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [template-chooser](http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/) to make your choice.

Check [JSRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html) too

Comment: All options disappear for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's not JQuery related, but I created my own templating solution a month ago that allows you to develop the template in HTML page (where IMO 'HTML' templates should be developed anyway).

https://github.com/jsweeneydev/HTMLTemplate

Very simple, no dependencies, and it doesn't (well, shouldn't) break anything like event listeners when adding elements to a page. Tested on independent projects.